# How to find the angle in between a corner of a triangle below of another?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows two triangles $ABC$ and $APC$ Find the
> angle $\angle APC=x$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&5^{\circ}\\
2.&10^{\circ}\\
3.&15^{\circ}\\
4.&20^{\circ}\\
5.&30^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

I've attempted to solve this problem, but other than just noticing there is an isosceles in $ABC$ and $BCP$ I don't know what else can be done to find the requested angle. Can someone help me in this?.

The most appropiate approach which would help me is some visual indication or drawing over my sketch so I can spot what other relation or identity to look for. Since this problem belongs to euclidean geometry I appreciate that an answer be using such sort of theorems and avoid trig approach.

Comment: $ABP$ is also isosceles. You do not need the theorems concerning circles.

Answer (score 1):

Put $B$ as the centre of a circle that goes through $A$. Then $C,P$ are also on the circle since $BA=BC=BP$. Since $AC$ is now a chord and it subtends an angle of $20^\circ$ at the centre, it must subtend $10^\circ$ at any point on the circle which is on the same side as $B$ – including $P$. Thus $x=10^\circ$.

We did not use $\angle CAP=20^\circ$ at all.